# php: parse_ini_file and require

Tags: php

I don't understand why when I try to do a require with the path taken from an array loaded with parse_ini_file, it gives me an error:

config.ini

```
[database]
db_engine   = "mysql"
db_host     = "127.0.0.1"
db_name     = "mydb"
db_user     = "root"
db_password = "password"

[application]
ROOT_DIR        = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myapp"
APP_DIR         = "/myapp"
SERVER_ROOT     = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
APP_ROOT_DIR    = "/myapp"
APP_ROOT_URL    = "/myapp"
```

page.php:

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    $config = parse_ini_file(dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ).'/config.ini');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($config);

    if (isset($config['APP_DIR'])){
       require_once($config['SERVER_ROOT'] . $config['APP_DIR'] . '/php/database.php');
       require $config['APP_DIR'] . '/html/header.html';
    }
?>
```

the error is:

> Warning: Undefined array key "APP_DIR" in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cert/php/page.php on line 11

Line 11 is the `require` line

Comment: Use `print_r($config);` to see what the array actually contains

Comment: @ADyson: I did it and it contains the right data!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and show us, so we've got the evidence?

Comment: `database.php` is probably overwriting the `$config` variable. Add `database.php` to your question.

Comment: Which line is line 11?

Comment: `Line 11 is the require line` - they said. So `isset($config['APP_DIR'])` returns `true` and `database.php` gets `required_once`. So `database.php` redefining the `$config` variable must be the problem.